# fetch index of row of csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I want to fetch index of row of csv file in php but i'm not able to use `indexOf` in php.

```
<?php
$value = $building."".$floor;
$val = $value.".".csv;
$file = fopen("csv/$val","r");
$chk=0;
$x1chk=0;
$x2chk=0;
$y1chk=0;
$y2chk=0;
while(!feof($file)) {
    $content = fgetcsv($file);
    $index = indexOf($content);
    $count1 = count($content);
}
?>
```

Comment: here what do you mean by `index` of row of csv???

Comment: you need to accept answers for all questions that solved them. Stack is about "give and take" and not "take, take, take".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a while loop
you can initialize a variable counter = 0 outside the loop and inside the loop you can increment it 
e.g

```
$counter=0;
while(!feof($file)){
    $content = fgetcsv($file);
    $counter++;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

use counter.

```
$count=0;
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, "\t")) !== false) {
   echo "<pre>";
     echo "line no. ".$count;
        print_r($line);     
   echo "</pre>";
   $count++;
 }
```

I have used "\t" for a tab separated csv file. For a comma separated file, use ","